# Why won't iTunes update my iPod Touch from 4.0b to 4.1?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, software-update

My iPod Touch shows the icon for "I won't do anything until you connect me to iTunes." When I obey, iTunes tells me:

> The software on the iPod has expired and must be updated to a newer version.

So I go to click the "Check for Update" button. But when I do, iTunes tells me:

> This version of the iPod software (4.0) is the current version.

When I click the "Restore" button, iTunes tells me:

> There was a problem downloading the software for the iPod. The requested resource was not found.

The current version on the iPod is 8A274b (4.0 beta), which has, of course, expired. I just updated iTunes, so I have the latest version of that. Does anyone know how I might fix this situation?

Comment: Also, under the "Check for Update" button, it says that it will check for updates again on 10/01/2010. Does that mean iTunes isn't even going to bother looking for an updated iOS until then?

Comment: Yes, but you can check for updates at any time by pressing that button.

Comment: I've tried everything I can think of. Taking it to a Genius Bar is not really an option since there's not one close enough and I need the iPod ready for a software demonstration tomorrow. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the 4.0 beta, you are able to download the 4.1 GM from developer.apple.com and use Xcode's Organizer or iTunes (by holding the option key when clicking restore) to choose the correct version of iOS (which is on the disk image you downloaded) to reload onto the iPod.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the beta, then you more than likely have a provisioning profiles on the phone. Make sure all expired profiles are deleted and you have a current, valid one installed. I've had issues related to those in the past.

Comment: I just gave it a try. Unfortunately, when I look at the iPod in Xcode Organizer, I can't change its provisioning profiles. Organizer just says "This device is expired and cannot be used with the iOS SDK. Please install a newer version of the OS." Do you know another way I can remove profiles?

Comment: You remove profiles stored on the iPhone on the iPhone itself. Just click on the cell that contains the profile that you wish to remove, and that will take you a detailed view of the profile. In there is a big, red `REMOVE` button. Can't miss it. Just be sure you aren't deleting the profile tied to the beta itself (if one is needed. I don't run the betas as a rule.)

Comment: As I said in the problem description, the iPod won't let me do anything until I've updated the OS. It just shows the "Connect to iTunes" icon and nothing else.

Comment: Ah. Now it's clear. I'm sure there is some file buried somewhere that you can edit, but at that point, I'd recommend heading over a Genius Bar if at all possible and let them sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm loathe to post this here since it's related to a jailbroken write-up, but seeing as how you've really no alternative, you might want to try the following to downgrade:

http://www.mobile-geeks.com/downgrade-ios-4.2-previous-jailbreakable-version-5843/

**Careful, though. This might brick it and then you'll really be in a mess.**

After downgrading, I imagine the update process will get you correctly back to 4.1.

Comment: The 4.2 betas start 8Cxxx not 8Axxx